# How to add List of emails in the reply to

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I want to send a mail with the header `reply-to`    I passed a list

```
replyto=['email1@gmal.com','email2@gmail.com']
```

into the add header method. here is my code.

```
message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message['to'] = ",".join(to)
message['from'] = sender
message['subject'] = subject
message.add_header('In-Reply-To', replyto)
```

The error I received is

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

So by the error, I get to know that there's no possibility that I can pass a list of emails. How to pass a list of emails in the header reply-to? Are there any other ways to get the job done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert List to string:

```
str1 = ','.join(replyto)
message.add_header('In-Reply-To', str1)
```

Comment: Joining on a comma makes more sense. `str1 = ', '.join(replyto)`

Comment: @user2883215 put comma ! other wise it's working thanks

Comment: @AayushMahajan yha!